# Properties of the algebraic self-difference set of Brownian motion zeros

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

As I was trying to exhibit new interesting(?) path transformations of Brownian motion, I became interested in
the (random) set of times $t$ such that $B(t)=B(t+1)=0$, where $B(t)$ denotes a standard Brownian motion.
Not surprisingly, I found that this set is almost surely empty. By scaling invariance of Brownian motion, the same result holds if $1$ is replaced by any positive real $s$.
Precisely, for all $s>0$, 
$$P[\exists t, B(t)=B(t+s)=0]=0.$$
Let me rephrase this a bit differently. Let $Z$ be the set of Brownian motion zeros and $D(Z)$ be the associated algebraic self-difference set
$$D(Z)=Z-Z=\{u-v : (u,v)\in Z^2\}.$$
In this setting, the preceding result says that for all $s\not=0$,
$$P[s\in D(Z)]=0.$$
Integrating this relation over $s$ with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ and exchanging the order of integration gives
$$E[\lambda(D(Z))]=0.$$
In other words, the set $D(Z)$ is almost-surely negligible.

I've never seen any property of this set in the literature, thus my question is:

*Is this a well-known result and, if so, what other properties are known, regarding its Hausdorff dimension for example ?*

**[EDIT]**
It seems that some of you doubt that the first probability is zero, so let me sketch a proof. (I apologize if there is a stupid mistake I've not been able to see). First, it is clear that,
$$P[\cup_{n\geq 0}\{B_n=B_{n+1}=0\}]=0$$
since this is a countable union of zero probability events. Therefore,
$$P[\exists t\geq 0, B_t=B_{t+1}=0]\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P[\exists t\in (n,n+1),B_t=B_{t+1}=0]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_n.$$
I asserts that each term $p_n$ inside the sum is equal to zero. For simplicity, I will do it only for $n=0$. (For other values of $n$, it suffices to condition first on the value of $B_n$ and then apply the same argument). Set $X_t=B_t$ and $Y_t=B_{t+1}-B_{1}$. Then,
$$p_0=P[\exists t\in(0,1),(X_t,X_1+Y_t)=(0,0)],$$
and it suffices to show that
$$P[\exists t\in(0,1),(X_t,x+Y_t)=(0,0)\vert X_1=x]=0$$
for (almost) all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, $X=(X_t,0\leq t\leq 1)$ and $Y=(Y_t,0\leq t\leq 1)$ are two independent Brownian motions, hence conditionally to $X_1=x$ the two-dimensional process $(X,x+Y)$ is a Brownian ``bridge'' (starting from $(0,x)$ and ending on the line $\{(x,r):r\in\mathbb{R}\}$). This process inherits from the standard two-dimensional Brownian motion the property that it does not hit $(0,0)$. Hence $p_0=0$.

Comment: Is it really clear that your first probability is zero? That definitely works for fixed $t$, but then you have uncountably many $t$ to consider. Or, viewed from another angle, $D(Z)$ is a set of differences of numbers taken from a $\dim$ $1/2$ Cantor set, so it's not clear there can be a quick argument showing this is small ($C-C$ contains an interval).

Comment: Well, I'm definitely not saying that this is straightforward, but I think I have a proof that the first probability is zero. I will try to post it in a few hours.

Comment: This looks fine to me. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: "Not surprisingly, I found that this set is almost surely empty." This isn't true: clearly there are times when $B(t) > B(t+1)$ and times when $B(t)<B(t+1)$, and so the existence of times when $B(t)=B(t+1)$ follows from the intermediate value theorem applied to $B(t)-B(t+1)$. Sorry if I have misinterpreted your original statement.

Comment: @Tom Hutchcroft : You're right, you have misunderstood the statement. I claim that there is no time $t$ such that both $t$ and $t+1$ are zeros of $B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding Hausdorff dimension $\dim_H$, the following holds:

$$
\dim_H(Z-Z)=1 \quad\text{a.s.}
$$

This is essentially a consequence of Marstrand's projection theorem, the (stochastic) self-similarity of $Z$, and the well known fact that $\dim_H Z=1/2$ (and the box counting dimension is also $1/2$).

Recall that Marstrand's projection theorem says that for a Borel set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, the orthogonal projection onto *almost every* line has Hausdorff dimension $\min(\dim_H E,1)$. In particular, taking $E=Z_1\times Z_2$, where $Z_1, Z_2$ are independent realizations of the zero set of Brownian bridge (see below for def.), then
$$
\dim_H(Z_1-\lambda Z_2)=1  \quad\text{for almost all }\lambda.
$$
(For "nice" sets such as $Z_1, Z_2$, we have $\dim_H(Z_1\times Z_2)=\dim_H(Z_1)+\dim_H(Z_2)$).

Now let us look at $Z-Z$. By scale invariance of Brownian motion, without loss of generality we can look at the zeros of the Brownian bridge instead, i.e. Brownian motion started at $0$ conditioned on $B(1)=0$. In this case, $Z$ can be constructed  by replacing $[0,1]$ by the random union $[0,\tau_1]\cup [\tau_2,1]$, where $\tau_1=\max\{ t\le 1/2: B_t=0\}$ and  $\tau_2=\min\{ t\ge 1/2: B_t=0\}$, and continuing inductively on these intervals. See the Chapter 14.3 of Lyons and Peres' [Probability on trees and networks](http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/book.pdf) for the details.

Conditioned on $\tau_1,\tau_2$, $Z_1$ has the law of $\tau_1 Z$, $Z_2$ the law of $(1-\tau_2)Z$ up to a translation, and $Z_1, Z_2$ are independent. On the other hand, the distribution of $(1-\tau_2)/\tau_1$ is absolutely continuous (it has some explicitly computable density). This means that $Z-Z\supset Z_1 - Z_2$ which, conditioned on the abs. continuous random variable $\lambda=(1-\tau_2)/\tau_1$ is homothetic to $Z'-\lambda Z''$, where $Z',Z''$ are two independent realizations of the zeros of the Brownian bridge. But we have seen before that for a.e. realization of $(Z', Z'')$, we have $\dim_H(Z'-\lambda Z'') = 1$ for almost all $\lambda$, so we are done (after Fubini).

In fact, using newer (and deeper) techniques such as those in M. Hochman's paper "[Dynamics on fractals and fractal distributions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3731)" and [my own paper with Hochman](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1956), one can show that a.s.
$$
\dim_H(Z-\lambda Z) = 1 \quad\text{for all }\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}.
$$